# What's the Language?

Tags: code-challenge, parsing, test-battery

Recently, the [PPCG design](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design) leaderboard has been having [some trouble](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/issues/16) parsing answer **html headers**.

In this challenge you'll be taking your own shot at parsing answer headers.

---

### Example Test Cases

These **example inputs** (**NOT** actual test cases), just so you can get the idea of how inputs **might** be like

```
Input: <h1>Python 3, 32 bytes</h1>
Desired Output: Python 3

Input: <h1>JavaScript, 13 chars / 32 bytes</h1>
Desired Output: JavaScript

Input: <b>VeryBadlyFormattedHeader v3 : (32 bytes)</b>
```

### Spec

**Your program should be 150 bytes or below**

You will be given a line of an answer header's html, you'll need to try to do your best to successfully extract the language. Input may contain unicode characters.

Output case matters.

### Tests

**[Github Gist with test cases](https://gist.github.com/vihanb/1d99599b50c82d4a6d7f)**

There is one test case per line. The format is:

```
<lang_name> - <rest_of_the_line_is_the_header>
```

### Scoring

Your score is:

```
 Number Correct
----------------
  Total Number
```

(which is a percent)

Tie-breaker is shortest code.

Comment: There should be a tie-breaker like shortest code since 100% score is very achievable.

Comment: The most common header style `#` is not even present in the test cases ?!

Comment: So the language is typically the first word the the input?

Comment: @edc65 I believe this is about parsing the *HTML output* of the answer, not the Markdown source.

Comment: @Kroltan uh thanks for clarifying

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex? Whatever next?

Comment: You should have made them output the byte number as well, that's been causing us just as much trouble...

Comment: @ETHproductions That could be made into a separate challenge considering its different enough

Comment: I would *highly* recommend changing the tie-breaker from shortest code to earlier submission. [Here's why](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8195#8195).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 100%, <s>75</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> <s>64</s> <s>59</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
<.*?>

(,| [-&(–5]| [0-7]\d)(?! W|...\)).*

2 |:
```

This is essentially code golf now, so I had to switch languages.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVrdctvGFb7XU6yVcULGEIhd/CsyPZLsxHHsqWJ56pk2mQwIrUjEIMEAoGV5fJGLXnR6m/SmM2n7DL3uw3TyBHkD9@wfsEsQFJ06nQyV3cX@nD2/3znrktbZInn79sj@@N54b29gvUF/PPhw8PP3P/hfQ9M5CL/@6mI4uHcLPX9j2/ZXw6H98d4eQW8O996@PbuuZ@gAHc3ImDUtdFSNPedoVI1Zyw2alsdbLkGT65pWRyNYsPd0NbmWi3lzQGz4bxn7Qwth4ulTn9HkPC2zZc3n4/FRgmYlvby7P6vrZXU4GtGqyJPFtLKLcjq6yl5ko2bJPippfnd/UVwWeV5c7Y@bL0ejZAxHBc1JeLx3klQzeQhrisFHNM@v5ShvW4jE@qoOH3Cok/8oeWnS3w7AVBcTN4IP2EF3Ee@SSN/891ldqdN520Keo09gu8nTWdNCEdZPPymTbHH5cfpC3Uv1hbiimMvGCwKUzpIySWtayo1PP5Db8gb2I7Hhk@Nnj3cXBJvdkQEbFOz3ovWrSE4NHpwHww6/xLCFQkdyPk/q67Ok7KNnmtWz1cROi/kovS5SOlILOiSpD4KsUKeq0VTMNRWkH7jQd53bIDEcefrc98qcmEkIC@PRzvhUyeXTDyxhaGIKiSJd8Oe0zIpVlSsra/qgdIZ53ad1seplYZlcARc1Fl7w6aN5UoGqjLIF/F3as3qed24iNhZ3YTcJlUPALm9hrF/r/0aG8FAdCy4WyJWnqy4zz0jM2MJN3zOtXbNzZuFwpO@rm3vS3Iybnz5K5srUoCmEioXPdPS9f5fWyUsqdxcdcSWMJUOdDbci5q2IheirZL7MKcrY3zld1EmdFYsN2uW6xtWK/FJdDZrwWdqJhRbFAkSzZNFkKhmWJrnyS7xtoSotSnqIAiK26yWPXT@MxP0DH53oDqLLXLadYG7QxJ6W4b746mPTz3S3IeJA4vf49KOqLrMXdBwz3RVNFPk6e3qViPtZIXffkA9ssknfQd2X8MnOr6ukLko7z1Z2RbsuC@ZIR@FtELtOhbghFrwgDt5JSwjebR5TQF/YNtZiPCyZUFpdJa967lgWFa3rJC0uaOsST5OaTovy@vBErO3cWu4pLu7iTiQcYDsSgcMdGwMnxXcvaP7RZfGyXKEBl0mAvDCE2OeDYAiEVYLcOIAfRq4v9U8Z9xCOcME6kjxteLt@oUv@cZmz23ToFis3gY53U4PRFj1w/ZudGlMEcTWhFK2pEMdrHHQkTAmHRnw@LS4vKTWwjD7EAou3q8oQtzkYxzIeBKFu7E9XVd3E3Qp2D2Px4Vl2AOgsSxHEXmGi2oiFsOEzH68SuQm0ABytHbEW2hk1JG4II0HblBpOukBpZ9jCjdCVRmhw9qmiAv6v8BtKFhfg0g0s8iSpZ3QO7jpVvlUbsTTYbXpuxXk7XBOFHYKdR@RG94EdI17CdeTx0JLBPZIaY6J8nl/Iudvg2XyyAmewgFBe8iUdLRc7aVFcaLHpgk2Wh0MNF@vDcB8TAnX0IJaqdvbwTHHi4Zk42GutxHXW1YM3SdvEbVNaFI51BdQiOmkiehys30nTKEGEi9ePW4v963hlG@@fgMcdNQs6nG@@NMyX@dxWKol50Z1tBHtEsDmAJmeq9D3K4cDWvqGMD5MKHHsuv8uexEXClLFjuCU9oVv3uBpb7tPFIqueZHU6gwWjb9mqDnP4XoIxgIEO1kFQP2o0s@H710leTNHx2WM5sx0AlkS9MIOYMIOEje8i0iB5U6pIaIisgZ2Yw86NHtFIywkES7Zd7AMuhTgJ0VfmHpKvqzxrlIC1BU0KdfyPeZKWGPnuZt@puT9va4LOgKHbYHKJzcJtYcOgXvNquHFMursgwl0QE74bnpXhyWIxHbeDElX6DIIqhKkGvRhvGOQiloNee5bceYs7B@X49VEMe3FvkCdakMdO2O@bt@0fyf0PO4S1cccchEW@cdgZLXNFEDThxl7HiDSegDka4fisuKLlOTN79JLcURsZgzLqNW6fSJeMA@Mgxz8@wQ92qE8cX5QZBHzIxkZiTcfViGFhAcEN6mgBqt2YYmItxZRIpG@vdwvYo60R@7TIiyWlHy2LF2UmWBe0@M9vg6fndhGXu1FyTbFNISQ0@KLMUvAdcMqyGIrpn5VF8VJ5NNnx/I5idQtzRDksW0x@bxv11zneX5mD9FTVlP3gjv2ERurwLFXWA60N2Xpr5v0YJY7tNqGII9sTnjkO7SBAeVoNhihN8nxLDUTWkt24F1EqZYfJUYO6ogYbtdYZNpQEwtsH4ValUi4WR123i4N2DDtbvQqzMkcW595ZJL7XcUnVTAEd6Y6aAeaLWtwZCF5DYqWTV9ELmRhDS@JIOVEjz33HhMZvciTSQmNIb8TGUXhT4SVuQHQkxBUF2zIebGY8kfOblV/dUFPC3SlqZc5ZIqRPNgMW8x3hXdiOnQbeQZyVKHedcXkyaSmEDguT73QUL2/zekAIyuRrUK9j8Bc0h2ngvVkD1hEd/W8rjWEHbyL/VHkDS0UoVIF/SyE/IhZ2Yws7ruVKM0bFql6uQJ9eJnl2gZZlMS05ogWtf54tLoqrCp0mebrKWSVFUrHxg9/BRb/VG4Np3QqvYI5XgAyOnCOAzT4wM@CCYNUYQBwgRBd@DgdikC7JyluIBmDOdzC6ZBd5MJSe/PODk@Pzz1X2pLoCAjfJQhuA/fb9LpQVWJ3OX3768d@//PTXv8DvT/D7G/z@Ibfe9Ik95XGGVmi0ZgR61kbarI3EvYhZK2XGgrbY/1Xm0xT1ILuBHKYVuOTZ8cHTZJe8eZ4sFtfwZzriKzry5qNN0iyYHe5aMcZRuF6N405elsr8zrPT8Ymydd6xeDmNzxm1N5SQ@lm5mi/731ThmlUyr2bJxRUIxZZXzoqRtq6L97SPjQPVVXxVUqQ9sDZ9AB/91bhAsC3wO1WAAfbQHWDEEN1VWtN4CBxaOIytKPStiBtGgD47GYo59BVNV3UyyWm39ObGnWN0@LkpgpmJw3Ga3rq1SXWApazQPS3yS7uqk/QFfQVSWUwp16RkFBAvdkcgsiAAxWG7yFIxMeoEk1QePknXMZtRqmpzREfLJt3mdcOY@/P3P0Ay7/SBRpi4bNJVHdkyFxW00T@Q@URbA24S0SVw5vkX5k5iAHvOptlGSvPe6oa@o96rGCTEdnRb2CSxsX@7k/mtZ3384f1kS9Ew6gaPCX9tXzWv700fiCHvJe8yb@h5m8q@m59sBDTBXrhrMU3F6Xjr46UJiXdCumaM6ZgYdncIHBz2yhqrv5uXVYmF3eN@us8p6@Dea7S/hb5tBus1gNyN5WvSbwZWvUg@LxthXBa5JES/uWiDPkzmy0/Q2eox8wo/gqoEnmcFUYSq71ZJySJmsayzecIKqPNskc2z1/Ri@AkI3Qp91/IBmWyambySM@U79mkyVyrG2wyYwiGDBfhyNxh2aZxoCecEdIDmSws9T8r7xXe3eiJYl4V81Tdi1W2C98fGNtLfci7dmNYDJo0i5qN7bQYNwNt0oMXDZ08eQ9Q6PT9Xs9sBAaFZxskhNO@GZi@UvXADTN1s6wBxYnX2l/EdWWdkfpZ3Bxr8GTYueO@0LKrqYFICPKYlWuMDGHrf54G3DqfIWlGUQWxPmwMyL6BLE1Y0lws@zRqQcLNQ2eT9MfvLBMiezwTglN4pL75lOKO9djsiSEUDdfqtIQLkHGO1XjFjsEonw7yYFvIWep@0pwHhD0pGHKKVzqy1QRWYyaYyL@bldFVbYKkn//dvN7x3ynL@LANUsegBH13Gyfn7Y9mQ//JJbJYmSuehZSEHOj//@e8dpftD8bqo6Wv0OKuWfUDyOr@irHhlL4rRazG/ix31jRghh4gBXW6EyvYYtx0G5e4NOR3SaSdXyAZIp0lYDbGib7gGLva@XGULepZNd3e8akWHZvVBgl0BDdBgnlxQlFzCjVE9o4zUPKcA9KQV/udf//wGfj3cmtM6sbcCxdCNnZGH4Wr7Y7kXJ2CTy@pgNuYNDAs9bDnTG1elvvLykmhrozzQqFHiuaaKkPF/AQ)

#### Verification

```
$ wget -q https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vihanb/1d99599b50c82d4a6d7f/raw/cd8225de96e9920db93613198b012749f9763e3c/testcases
$ grep -Po '(?<= - ).*' < testcases > input
$ grep -Po '^.*?(?= - )' < testcases > output
$ mono retina/Retina.exe headers.ret < input | head -n -1 | diff -s - output
Files - and output are identical
```

#### How it works

The code consists of three simple substitutions (or eliminations). Instead of trying to match the language name, we get rid of all parts of the input string that do form part of it.

1. `<.*?>` will match all HTML tags, so the substitution will eliminate them from the input.

   `.*?` matches any amount of characters, but since `?` makes the quantifier *lazy*, it will match the least amount possible that still allows the entire pattern to match. This avoid deleting the entire input, which will always begin with a `<` and end with a `>`.

   The language name now begins with the first character of the remaining modified input string.
2. After the language's name, we will almost always find one of the following endings:

   `,`, `-`, `&`, `(`, `–`, `5`, or a space followed by two digits.

   The first two endings are rather common, and `Python 2 &amp; PuLP...` should be parsed as `Python 2`, `Ruby (2.2.2p95)...` as `Ruby`, `>PHP – 3302 bytes` as `PHP`, and `Perl 5...` as `Perl`.

   `(,| [-&(–5]| \d\d).*` would match all these endings (and all characters after them), but it will result in a few false positives:

   - `,` will match the comma in the language name `Help, WarDoq!`.
   - `(` will match the version of `JavaScript (ESx)` and `Java (1.8)`.
   - `\d\d` will match the version in `Ti-Basic 84`.

   We can fix the third problem case by using `[0-7]\d` instead of `\d\d`, to avoid matching the `8` in `84`.

   For the other problem cases, we use the negative lookahead `(?! W|...\))` that will prevent the preceding pattern from matching if it is followed by `W` (as in `Help, WarDoq!`) or by exactly three characters and a closing parenthesis (as in `(ES6)` or `(1.8)`).

   Putting it all together, `(,| [-&(–5]| [0-7]\d)(?! W|...\)).*` matches everything after the language name.
3. We're left with two problem cases:

   ```
   <h1>Python <s>2</s> 3, <s>255</s> <s>204</s> <s>180</s> 178 bytes</h1>
   <h1><a href="http://sylwester.no/zozotez/" rel="nofollow">Zozotez Lisp</a>: 73</h1>
   ```

   gets parsed as

   ```
   Python 2 3
   Zozotez Lisp:
   ```

   We can fix the first by removing `2`  and the second one by removing `:` from the output.

   This is achieved by replacing `2 |:` with the empty string.

Answer (score 16):

## Bash, 100%, 100 bytes

```
sed sX..s.2./s.XX|grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]+?(?=(,(?! W)| [-&–5]| ?<| [0-79]\d| ?\((?!E|1\.)))'|head -1
```

Try it online on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/WCeI29).

#### Verification

```
$ wget -q https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vihanb/1d99599b50c82d4a6d7f/raw/cd8225de96e9920db93613198b012749f9763e3c/testcases
$ grep -Po '(?<= - ).*' < testcases > input
$ grep -Po '^.*?(?= - )' < testcases > output
$ while read line; do bash headers.sh <<< "$line"; done < input | diff -s - output
Files - and output are identical
```

Comment: Huh, I really thought this would *very* difficult... nice job!

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 78.38% (76 bytes)

```
l{_'>#)>_c'<=}g_'<#<_{",-"&}#)_{_1$=',=+(<}{;}?
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bHtfJz4jKT5fYyc8PX1nXyc8IzxfeyIsLSImfSMpX3tfMSQ9Jyw9Kyg8fXs7fT8&input=PGgyPlB5dGgsIDxzPjQwPC9zPiA8cz4zNjwvcz4gPHM-MzQ8L3M-IDMyIGJ5dGVzPC9oMj4) or [count the correct headers](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MTg1e2xfXyIgLSAiIzpJMys-Okw7STwKICAgIEx7Xyc-Iyk-X2MnPD19Z18nPCM8X3siLC0iJn0jKV97XzEkPScsPSsoPH17O30_Cj19Kl06Kw&input=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).

Answer (score 4):

## Jolf, 13 bytes, 85.94%, noncompeting

```
ρΥpΔid=',H',E
  pΔi         remove all HTML tags from input, preserving content
 Υ   d=',H     slice from beginning until a member is a comma
ρ         ',E  replace said comma with the empty string
```

I had this update on my computer. It was to my chagrin that I had forgotten to update the respective code for the interpreter. I don't feel like shooting for 100%. Maybe everyone should format their headers the same ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Stripping tags is a good idea. That saved three bytes in my Retina answer.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! Glad it helped.